# Precedence of chained unary operators in SVA assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

For a tool, I'm trying to correctly parse SystemVerilog assertions, and am confused about the correct precedence for certain expressions.  The SystemVerilog standard has a nice table where they say that `not` > `until` > `always` for precedence.  But I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work with alternations of the unary operators.

For instance, since `not` is higher precedence than `until`, we should obviously have:

```
    not r1 until r2   ---->   (not r1) until r2
```

And since `until` is higher precedence than `always`, we should obviously have:

```
    always r1 until r2   ---->  always (r1 until r2)
```

But what's the proper way to interpret the following?

```
    not always r1 until r2
```

I can imagine that two interpretations might be correct:

- `not always (r1 until r2)`, since `until` binds more tightly than `always`, or
- `(not always r1) until r2`, since `not` binds more tightly than `until`

It looks like NCVerilog 15.10-p001 uses the first interpretation.  Is there anywhere in the standard that discusses whether this is correct that I may have missed?  It seems difficult to encode NCVerilog's precedence rules into a nice grammar...

Answer (score 0):

Normally programming languages define unary operators as always having a higher priority than binary operators. In this case `always` is a unary operator with lower precedence than `until`, a binary operator.

Perl also has a similar situation, with the `not` operator (unary) having a lower precedence than `&&` (binary). Conceptually, your expression is similar to the following Perl expression:

```
! not $r1 && $r2
```

If you try to evaluate this for all values of `r1` and `r1`, you'll see that Perl interprets it as:

```
! not ($r1 && $r2)
```

This is conceptually the same interpretation as your simulator. Why it's like this I can't definitely say. I guess it's because interpretation 2 would violate `until`'s precedence over `always`.

Comment: @JaredDavis You could rephrase the question to ask why the operator precedence works like that in Perl and maybe get a reference to some normative document.

Comment: @JaredDavis This video might also be interesting for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5UWAaw_byw Based on the rules of precedence described in the standard and the EBNF in Annex A you could construct an operator precedence parser like the guy describes.